# How to disable shortcuts in urxvt?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mc, rxvt

I have installed **urxvt** and **mc**.
There is a combination <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> in urxvt and the same combination in mc.
When i use mc through urxvt and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, command of the urxvt works instead of command of the mc.
How can i disable shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> in urxvt in order to use this combination in mc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the `searchable-scrollback` feature by putting this in your .Xresources:

```
URxvt.perl-ext-common: "default, -searchable-scrollback"
```

Source: [urxvt manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/urxvt) (under `perl-ext` in the **Resources** section)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the possibility of using `searchable-scrollback`, with a different keybinding (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>) then you can add the following to your `.Xresources`:

```
URxvt.searchable-scrollback: Meta-Shift-S
```

According to the [manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/rxvt-unicode-256color/urxvt.1.en.html) this method is deprecated, but it works and what should have been the correct alternative:

```
URxvt.keysym.Meta-S:  builtin-string:
URxvt.keysym.Meta-Shift-S:  searchable-scrollback:start
```

doesn't seem to work for me (`M-S-s` is enabled, but `M-s` is not disabled for `searchable-scrollback`).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have to compile it yourself, using the `--disable-perl` option.

See this mailing-list discussion where its developer gives his viewpoint on the matter: [Re: disable all keybindings](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.terminal-emulators.rxvt-unicode.general/1376) (2013).

Comment: Maybe it helps, but it is long task, so i haven't tried.